# Rails 5 + Bootstrap 4 nav-bar shown collapsed where it should not

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Full code https://github.com/tenzan/shop/tree/bootstrap

**application.html.erb:** (Reference: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Shop</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |key, message| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
       <div><%= message %></div>
     </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    </div
  </body>
</html>
```

When I see from a desktop it shows as [image]

instead of [image]

Comment: I think that is the default behavior of the nav bar on small screens, or maybe with screen with low resolution. That might be the your case?

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using Chrome browser from macbook pro retina display.

Comment: When I implement your code in mi environment, It looks all items one next to each other (not collapsed). But the layout is a bit weird.. let me work a little be to see if I can find something.

Comment: Change the **toggler** for **toggle** specially in `class="navbar-toggle"`.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't figure out what you mean. Can you please be more specific where and how to change?

Comment: Here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/ it says `.navbar-toggle` is now `.navbar-toggler`

Comment: I wasn't aware of the change on `navbar-toggle`, I guess my version is older.

Comment: I have the same exact problem and I'm using `.navbar-toggler`.